# Can a sidebar span two zones in omega 3 theme?

Tags: theming

I'm a bit of a newbee with Omega 3. I am having trouble arranging a grid which has a vertical sidebar span two zones. See the attached  diagram to understand the design requirements. I need to have a left sidebar and content block both appear under the header, and a right sidebar that spans both the the header and the content.

I would like to know if it is possible to create such a grid within the standard Omega UI, or if not how can this be accomplished.

Thanks!

[image: Required design grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with the way the HTML is built, it goes

- zone-wrapper div (if used)
- - zone dov
- - - region div

In your case, I would leave the Header zone empty (make sure the checkbox for forced rendering is off), and then move all of your regions to the Content zone.  In the grand scheme of things, there is nothing special about the Header zone.  I am looking at one of my sites now, and I left Header empty.

With the default templates, the Content zone also contains the Breadcrumb and Messages, so you may need to tweak this a bit to output the regions specifically to get these in the proper place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Question is if I put the header in the content zone, how can I have the left sidebar as a separate block under the header? Can I somehow add a view block within the content zone?

Comment: @DoviG. You would keep the left sidebar as a region and just assign the proper gird classes.  Omega just handles the regions.  You add blocks to the regions with the normal methods from the block management page.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for my repeated questions, as I am pretty new to this. I am afraid I did not explain myself properly. If I understand correctly you suggest adding the header and main content into a single region in the content zone and have them aligned vertically in the region. How do I have the left sidebar block appear under the header next to the content like in the diagram above? Is this doable?